# How do I correctly add a webdriver's location to the system's PATH?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, firefox

I would like to use selenium (3.141.0) with the Firefox (89.0.1) browser to do some webscraping.

I work on macOS Big Sur 11.4 and with Python 3.9.

The following code throws an error:

```
#! python3
# openFirefox.py - Opens a Firefox browser window with selenium.

from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
type(browser)
browser.get('https://inventwithpython.com')
```

Error message:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'geckodriver'
```

and

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

I am aware that this is a common problem users have and there are different posts on SO, but I still haven't found a good way to solve the problem.

I have dowloaded the latest geckodriver version here:
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

```
geckodriver-v0.29.1-macos.tar.gz
```

My PATH variable looks as follows:

[image]

My idea is to add geckodriver to my PATH environment variable and put it in the following directory:

```
/usr/local/bin
```

The file is in there:
[image]

and it is executable:
[image]

But the same error messages come again.

I have read some post that I can write my code like that (and this is one solution):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
type(browser)
browser.get('https://inventwithpython.com')
```

I still want to find out why the solution with adding the geckodriver directory to my PATH variable does not work.

To all the webscrapers out there: How can I tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter where the driver is, you just need to give the correct path. Put the driver next to your .py and try this.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='./geckodriver')
type(browser)
browser.get('https://inventwithpython.com')
```